# Fix slow startup after utility disk repair on a SSD

Tags: ssd, startup, disk-utility, repair

I have a 250Gb Samsung SSD 840 series with Trim support enabled installed on a mid-2009 13" Macbook pro running Snow Leopard (10.6.8, 2.26GHz, 8Gb of RAM) and I experience extremely slow startup after trying to repair my ssd with the disk utility.

My disk was starting to boot a bit slower than usually and There were permission errors that I fixed with the disk utility and then when I verified the disk I saw there were erros so I inserted my Snow Leopard installation DVD and tried to fix them (huge mistake)... The disk utility reported mistakes and said it could not fix the disk, I was afraid of losing my data because but I didn't lose anything.

However when I boot now there is a grey screen for around 30 seconds, then there is the loading progress bar and apple's logo and it takes more than 2 minutes to startup  Besides I have no time machine backup because of some external hard drive problems I had recently.

Is there any way for me to fix it without formatting the disk? If I upgrade to Mountain Lion without formatting the drive will it fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem may arise because the `Disk Utility` did not correctly finish the repair of your disk, and by doing so did not give back the boot flag to your SSD.

1. Go to `System Prefences > Startup Disk` and select your SSD as a Startup Disk
2. Try to reboot and see if it changes anything

Else, read this thread with many different, quite helpful inputs:

> https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4550751?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I had tried to choose the Startup Disk first it didn't work, I tried to  burn a CD to update the firmware of my SSD and I wasted 2 CDs for nothing. I tried a bunch of things and after booting from an external drive running Mountain Lion and updating it I had to reboot but since it was an external device it restarted on the internal drive and oddly it started booting like before. I don't know how it has been fixed but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

For other users, I had a similar problem: iMac late 2012, factory fusion, first weeks 5 seconds boot, lastly 1 minute).
I did a lot of search and whole things like:

- Repair from Disk utility app
- [Executing from safe mode command](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1417)

But after accessing to System information, I saw a `fsck` log, which brougth me [to this solution](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4831564). Although some users report that it doesn't work, it worked for me: iMac boots again in 5 sec.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my problem was due to a failing sata cable. Since I have replaced it, I do not have this problem anymore.